# GcmTaskService use for batch event tracking

Tags: android, extras, gcm-network-manager, gcmtaskservice

I titled my question this way since many people might be using GcmTaskService for tasks such as event tracking which don't need to happen immediately. Tracking is a great example of a task that can be postponed to when the device is charging, or when the radio is awake for other reasons anyway.

However, when it's finally time to send the request, I have quite a bit of tracking data to dispatch to the server, and it doesn't fit inside the OneoffTask extras (10240 bytes). Is there a better way to communicate the parameters for the request? Am I using GcmNetworkManager correctly?

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: I think you are allowed to create a series of oneofftasks, so why not break up the data and send?

Comment: I did break up the data, but I had to go from 30 events per request to 5 events, which multiplies the number of requests accordingly. It's not terrible but I was wondering if that's maybe not what these extras are meant for.